Is there a way to disable the contact card that pops up when you hover over a contact in Outlook (2024)?
There's this annoying feature in MS Office Outlook (v 1.2024.903.200) on Windows where when you hover your mouse cursor over somebody's email address it opens up this big contact card that expands and takes up the whole screen and, more importantly, stops you from typing your email.
This is super annoying because usually when I click in to compose an email and then move my hand off my mouse, the cursor naturally settles a few pixels away over an email address, which steals focus and stops me from being able to type my message.
Having done a Google searching it appears that, in previous Office versions, there was a registry key you could edit that would disable this functionality, but it seems like it's no longer active with this new version of outlook.

The registry key in that blog article is Outlook client version specific: did you transpose the value to the Outlook client version that you have installed?

I tried, but on my version there was no matching key or entry. I’m guessing it’s changed with the latest version of Office 365.

As i know, there's no such built-in feature in Outlook to archive your requirements.

Are you running Office 365, or Office 2024? Office  typically refers to the LTSC version of Office, while Office 365 is the iterating version with the subscription license. Because they are different, it is important to use the correct label to refer to the version of Office you are using.

Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. It's kind of confusing. If I open Word and go to my account on a browser it says it's 'Microsoft 365 Business Premium', but in my Windows applications menu it has listings for both Microsoft 365 and apps like 'Outlook (New)'....??

I have confirmed that, in Office 365, the article you were referring to still works.
Here are two things to be aware of regarding this, necessary to understand the solution:

The 14.0 refers to the Office version, and so you'll need to select the version number appropriate to your installed Office client. For my Office 365 build 2406 client I used the 16.0 registry key.
If a registry key or value doesn't exist, just create it. On my system there was no ContactCard key, so I created this and the TurnOffHoverFunctionality DWORD value under it and set that value.

So, the solution for me was to "go" to this Key (keeping in mind point 2 above):
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ContactCard

and set this value:
TurnOffHoverFunctionality

to:
1

Close and reopen the Outlook client and the contact cards no longer pop up as my house hovers over them, but I can still view them by double-clicking on the contact.

Thanks for this; unfortunately it didn't work for me, and I should also mention I didn't have any of the registry entries you mentioned after 'Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft' so had to create all those keys.
Could this perhaps mean I'm creating them in the wrong place for my version of Outlook? I do have entries for '15.0', '16.0' and '8.0' within my 'Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office' folder but I've added the 'ContactCard' key/value in all of them and it still hasn't worked.

Did you try adding those following, like I note in point 2? Don't add them outside that path. Make a backup of your current registry, and create the entire path from the point where it is missing.

Yes I did, I have that entire path with a DWORD value inside it but the popups persist.
https://imgur.com/a/PUgtYpK
Maybe I'm missing something really obvious here....?

You might try accessing Local Group Policy, setting a User Office policy to see if it creates the keys. Is your installed Office version 64bit or x86 (32bit)?

Thanks for the tips. It looks like it's 64-bit. I also found the version no: 1.2024.903.200
It looks like there's no mention of Office policies anywhere in Local Group Policy Editor. Might this be indicative of why the registry keys aren't doing anything?
